# "concurrently: command not found" despite being installed

Tags: javascript, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to run two scripts concurrently, and I found this package `concurrently` that supposedly would help me. I did `npm install concurrently --save` and it's listed in my `package.json`. When I go to run it, however, it throws:

`concurrently: command not found`

I don't understand why it can't find it despite being installed. I've set up the commands as shown [here](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently#usage), so I know it can't be that. I've checked earlier instances of this issue, but it appears to be outdated. Is there another way I can check if this works, or should I try something else?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you post your package.json please just to make sure? Maybe try putting `npx` in front of your commands

Comment: I had to run this: sudo npm install -g concurrently

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you install using `npm install` without specifying the `global` flag `-g`, you are installing the module to your projects `node_modules` folder. If that module has any runnable binaries, they will be added to `node_modules/.bin` - so you should be able to run your local version of `concurrently` by running `node_modules/.bin/concurrently` (or from any folder in your project `$(npm bin)/concurrently`). I personally prefer using the project's local dependencies over installing global ones so I have the option to use a different version in another project.

If you put a script into the [package.json `"scripts"` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) it will reference these locally installed without having to specify the full path because `npm run` adds your projects `node_modules/.bin` to your path.

If you're having issues, I would start by checking the `node_modules/.bin` folder and verifying that the binary for your script actually exists.

Comment: It worked using `sudo`. I tried it with without it and it said I had access denied.

Answer (score 4):

This issue also comes up when there is a dash "-" in your folder name. i.e. (/developer/api-movies) or even (/developer-apps/apiMovies. Use camelCase throughOut rather than dashes.